# The constructor PrintStream is undefined (LibGDX)

Tags: java

I run in one problem (error) which I don't know how to fix because it shows up only when I try to run HTML version.

The error is:

```
The constructor PrintStream(OutputStream, boolean) is undefined
```

In the top of application i have

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
```

then `PrintStream out;`

and then

```
try {
    SocketHints hint = new SocketHints();
    hint.connectTimeout=1000;
    client = Gdx.net.newClientSocket(Net.Protocol.TCP, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 66, hint);
    out = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream(), true);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
```

Error is at line:

```
out = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream(), true);
```

Error:

```
Validating units:
[ERROR] Line 71: The constructor PrintStream(OutputStream, boolean) is undefined
[ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
```

In one of my attempts to fix it I added to class extends `PrintStream` but that didn't help.

Comment: At a guess you have your own class called `PrintStream`.

Comment: Mhh  in my project structure there isn't any printstream class . [link](http://prntscr.com/8ld5qj) .